# Add a bank card to Apple Wallet

Tags: ios, applet, wallet

I have a task to add a bank card to apple wallet, I know that me need to get permission from Apple for this. Tell me, what data does the map need that to be added to the apple wallet? Number, cvc, name of the holder ...?

And I'm trying to create a PKAddPaymentPassViewController object:

```
[[PKAddPaymentPassViewController alloc] initWithRequestConfiguration: passDetails delegate: self]
```

The object always returns nill, in this case

```
[PKAddPaymentPassViewController canAddPaymentPass]
```

Returns YES. I understand that this object will nill until Apple allows to add cards to Apple Wallet?

Comment: What should be implementation for PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that me need to get permission from Apple for this

&

> I understand that this object will nill until Apple allows to add
>   cards to Apple Wallet?

Yes, you're correct.

> Adding payment passes requires a special entitlement **issued by Apple**.
>   Your app must include this entitlement before this class can be
>   instantiated. For more information on requesting this entitlement, see
>   the Card Issuers section at https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/.

Comment: What should be implementation for PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate methods?